# ListView getFirstVisiblePosition

Tags: android, listview

Добрый день, пытаюсь высчитать в OnTouchEvent item на который нажали. Написал следующий алгоритм.

> case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
>
> ```
>           x = (int) event.getX();
>           y = (int) event.getY();
>           int pos[] = new int[2];
>           v.getLocationOnScreen( pos );
>           ListView list = (ListView) findViewById( R.id.list );
>           int fpos[] = new int[2];
>           int f = list.getFirstVisiblePosition();
>           list.getChildAt( f ).getLocationOnScreen( fpos );
>           int res = fpos[1] - pos[1];
>           for ( int i = 0; i < f; i++ )
>           {
>               res -= list.getChildAt( i ).getHeight();
>           }
>           int q = 0;
>           for ( int i = f; i < list.getLastVisiblePosition() && res  y; i++ )
>           {
>               q = i;
>               res += list.getChildAt( i ).getHeight();
>           }
>
>           Log.i( "asd", "" + ( q ) );
>           break;
> ```

Собственно вылетает ошибка на этой строке res += list.getChildAt( i ).getHeight();.
Лог:

> 07-31 14:14:49.779:
> E/AndroidRuntime(15641): FATAL
> EXCEPTION: main 07-31 14:14:49.779:
> E/AndroidRuntime(15641):
> java.lang.NullPointerException 07-31
> 14:14:49.779: E/AndroidRuntime(15641):
>   at
> ru.qbit.vox2box.MainActivity.onTouch(MainActivity.java:213)
> 07-31 14:14:49.779:
> E/AndroidRuntime(15641):  at
> android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:5544)
> 07-31 14:14:49.779:
> E/AndroidRuntime(15641):  at
> android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1951)
> 07-31 14:14:49.779:
> E/AndroidRuntime(15641):  at
> android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1712)
> 07-31 14:14:49.779:
> E/AndroidRuntime(15641):  at
> android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1957)
> 07-31 14:14:49.779:
> E/AndroidRuntime(15641):  at
> android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1684)
> 07-31 14:14:49.779:
> E/AndroidRuntime(15641):  at
> android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1957)
> 07-31 14:14:49.779:
> E/AndroidRuntime(15641):  at
> android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1684)
> 07-31 14:14:49.779:
> E/AndroidRuntime(15641):  at
> android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1957)
> 07-31 14:14:49.779:
> E/AndroidRuntime(15641):  at
> android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1684)
> 07-31 14:14:49.779:
> E/AndroidRuntime(15641):  at
> android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1957)
> 07-31 14:14:49.779:
> E/AndroidRuntime(15641):  at
> android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1684)
> 07-31 14:14:49.779:
> E/AndroidRuntime(15641):  at
> android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1957)
> 07-31 14:14:49.779:
> E/AndroidRuntime(15641):  at
> android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1684)
> 07-31 14:14:49.779:
> E/AndroidRuntime(15641):  at
> com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1912)
> 07-31 14:14:49.779:
> E/AndroidRuntime(15641):  at
> com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1371)
> 07-31 14:14:49.779:
> E/AndroidRuntime(15641):  at
> android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2364)
> 07-31 14:14:49.779:
> E/AndroidRuntime(15641):  at
> com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1860)
> 07-31 14:14:49.779:
> E/AndroidRuntime(15641):  at
> android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:5729)
> 07-31 14:14:49.779:
> E/AndroidRuntime(15641):  at
> android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:2960)
> 07-31 14:14:49.779:
> E/AndroidRuntime(15641):  at
> android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2469)
> 07-31 14:14:49.779:
> E/AndroidRuntime(15641):  at
> android.view.ViewRootImpl.processInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:845)
> 07-31 14:14:49.779:
> E/AndroidRuntime(15641):  at
> android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2478)
> 07-31 14:14:49.779:
> E/AndroidRuntime(15641):  at
> android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
> 07-31 14:14:49.779:
> E/AndroidRuntime(15641):  at
> android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
> 07-31 14:14:49.779:
> E/AndroidRuntime(15641):  at
> android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
> 07-31 14:14:49.779:
> E/AndroidRuntime(15641):  at
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native
> Method) 07-31 14:14:49.779:
> E/AndroidRuntime(15641):  at
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
> 07-31 14:14:49.779:
> E/AndroidRuntime(15641):  at
> com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:787)
> 07-31 14:14:49.779:
> E/AndroidRuntime(15641):  at
> com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:554)
> 07-31 14:14:49.779:
> E/AndroidRuntime(15641):  at
> dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native
> Method)

Comment: P.S. вылетает не всегда, а при прокрутке списка.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ListView getChildAt returning null for visible children](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6766625/listview-getchildat-returning-null-for-visible-children)